# How to use itfoxtec-identity-saml2with Forgerock SSO

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am trying to use the itfoxtec-identity-saml2 code samples from Github to use as my ASP.NET client app to autenticate with Forgerock. But it seems the are no samples-code-documentation on this. Am I moving the wrong path?

Is itfoxtec-identity-saml2 even compatible with Forgerock SSO server?

Answer (score 0):

ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 support SAML 2.0 and basically supports all IdPs which support SAML 2.0.

It looks like Forgerock SSO support SAML 2.0 in this guide:  https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/6.5/saml2-guide/
It looks